# Dummy Data Example

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a dummy data example so I can better ask my question to the forum.  Basically I  am trying to create a PDF with 6 graphs on one page of paper.  Heres the example code I have been trying to build.

```
#Dummy data
Data1 <- data.frame(flow = c(8,8.5,6,7.1,9), SP_elev = c(20,11,5,25,50))
Data2 <- data.frame(flow = c(7,7.2,6.5,8.2,8.5), SP_elev = c(13,15,18,25,19))
Data3 <- data.frame(flow = c(2,3,5,7,9), SP_elev = c(20,25,28,30,35))
Data4 <- data.frame(flow = c(1,4,6,8,9), SP_elev = c(13,15,18,25,19))
Data5 <- data.frame(flow = c(1,4,6,8,9), SP_elev = c(13,15,18,25,19))
Data6 <- data.frame(flow = c(1,4,6,8,9), SP_elev = c(22,23,25,27,29))

#Create Vector list (in place of list.files)
dataframes = list("Data1" = data1, 
                  "Data2" = data2, 
                  "Data3" = data3,
          "Data4" = data4,
          "Data5" = data5,
          "Data6" = data6)

# open the PDF device
pdf(file="Dummy_Example.pdf", paper="letter", height=10, width=8)

#Create array of plots 
par(mfrow=c(3,2))

#plot a with regression model
for (i in dataframes) {

plot (i[,c('flow', 'SP_elev')], xlab=expression(paste("Discharge (", ft^3, "/s)",sep = "")), ylab= "Elevation (m)", tck=0.02, adj = 0.5)

}

# close the PDF device
dev.off()
```

I keep getting the error

```
Error in i[, c("flow", "SP_elev")] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: the short and bad fix would be `get(i)`

Comment: @baptiste where would i put that?  in the plot function?

Comment: your `dataframes` is in fact a character vector, not a list. you should use `dataframes <- list()` as baptiste suggests

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your data.frames in a list,

```
dataframes = list("Data1" = Data1, 
                  "Data2" = Data2, 
                  "Data3" = Data3) # I gave up here
```

the rest of your code should work.

Comment: I changed the character vector to a list and I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: you're misspelling Data, don't forget the capital D

Comment: amazing.  It worked.  I guess my eyes are getting tired.  Thanks a lot.